# Explanation of the YouTube warning: Experiment: There may be confidential content in your search results. Please do not share outside Google

Tags: youtube

If you now search for anything in YouTube, it gives this weird warning:

[image]

What does it mean?

I expect it will probably be just a bug/mistake, but there is only speculation going on and I would like a definite answer.

Comment: So the first thing you do is share this outside Google? :)

Comment: I think any answer to this would be just a guess, but this looks like some internal experiment within Google that was mistakenly rolled out publicly. Will probably be removed really soon.